# Can login in webamin but not via ssh

Tags: centos, ssh

I made a few changes to `sshd_config` now I am unable to login via ssh but able to login in webamin on CentOS 6 based VPS.

The problem is with root as well as user.

I reversed the changes in `sshd_config` and restarted `sshd` but no help.

Can anyone let me know how to start ssh and ftp login again without affecting webamin.

The error I get after entering password for ssh is: `Permission denied, please try again.`

Comment: what changes you did in your ssh config file can you paste here sshd_config here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the logs on the server - they should provide much more detail than the `Permission denied` error you are seeing on the client.

- Debian: `/var/log/auth.log`
- CentOS: `/var/log/secure`